# How to move Vim status bar from bottom to top?

Tags: vim, configuration

How to configure Vim by editing `~/.vimrc` or by other way, so that the status bar can be displayed at the top of the window.

What I mean is the bottom information bar, which appears like `index.html 22L,538C written 15,3-9 ALL`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing me! Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, I'm reword people who helped me right now.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/112222/is-it-possible-to-have-the-status-line-on-top-of-the-window and offtopic.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai - It is a duplicate, yes, but it is not offtopic. Vim questions that range outside the usage of normal users, are perfectly ontopic here.

Comment: @Idigas : and who decides what is a normal user? A simple configuration question is programming related? (Even if this option does not exist?)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai - Vim questions in general are ontopic here, since they fit rather nicely under "software tools commonly used by programmers". I have my own criteria - if it's in the help, or in the vimtutor it can go to superuser. Otherwise, if it takes a bit of effort or more than 10 minutes of searching it stays here. Were this a simple configuration question, I would've voted it for moving - since it is not, I didn't. Happy?

Comment: "in the help" - easy to find.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai:  See "[Vim questions: SO or SU?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925)"

Comment: I'm sorry, should I just close this question?

Comment: Yes as it is answered correctly by @Idigas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can't be done ...

I mean, you can download vim's sources, and go from there, but natively, no. Not that I know.

You can put some info in the title, you can read some info from the tabline, but the statusline stays where it is. Sorry :/

Comment: Of the near infinite configuration options of vim, super surprised the last-line can't be moved to the top.

Comment: Now it can be done in neovim https://stackoverflow.com/a/75682901/3627387

Answer (score 13):

The answer: utilize a (static) "tabline".

`vim` has tablines (which are located at the top), and a status line (which is located at the bottom), utilize a static tabline for the same functions as the statusline

inside `vimrc`:

```
----- begin cut -------
"turn off status line
"set laststatus=0
set ls=0
set showtabline
set tabline="what status line equals, or equaled or whatever"
"set or change the color of the tabline
hi tablinefill cterm=none ctermbg=blue ctermfg=white gui=none guibg=blue guifg=white
------ end cut -------
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there wondering, you can do this with [lualine](https://github.com/hoob3rt/lualine.nvim). It requires nvim.

Answer (score 0):

My [original answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1772779/591586)

If you are using `neovim` you can set it via new option in 0.8+ called `winbar` that allows having top [statusline per window](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/18562)

Here is small video explanation by [@tjdevries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKW_SUucO-k)